# MVVMCross + SQLCipher = impossible?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross, sqlcipher

I'm a beginner in developing iOS apps with Xamarin and MVVMCross. MVVMCross fits perfectly on top of the Xamarin developing platform and its features are outstanding! I've watched several of the MVVMCross N=x tutorial videos on youtube, what helps me a lot to understand how to use the framework. 
The iOS app i'm currently working on should use a database encryption, to secure the data. Therefore i wanted to use the Xamarin SQLCipher component. And here come my problems into play:

As far as i know it is a platform specific library, but i wanted to write a MVVMCross-SQLCipher-plugin, like the SQLite Community Plugin, which is separated in a PCL core and a platform specific library. Any suggestions how i can do this or is it impossible because of the SQLCipher-architecture?

Answer (score 2):

We used the standard SQLite implementation included in MvvmCross and just swapped the binaries for SQLite to SQLCipher out and it works fine.

I believe all the calls are the in both binaries so there should be little else requried just make sure you set a password on the database when you do:

```
new SQLiteConnection(databasePath, password)
```

Comment: Currently i'm stuck a little bit. My approach was to create a new SQLCipher-MVVMCross-Plugin (separated in a PCL Core and platform specific library). I've created a PCL core lib, which includes the original SQLite lib (the Core part). If i create the platform specific plugin part, i'll have to implement the SQLite's original interface. I can include the SQLCipher lib here, but it doesn't implement the original interfaces of the SQLite lib. (See a more detailed MVVMCross-Plugins presentation: https://speakerdeck.com/cirrious/plugins-in-mvvmcross). How did you solved this problem?

Comment: SQLCipher should have everything in SQLite implemented in exactly the same way even in the same namespace so it should be a direct binary swap. Can you tell me which interface you're refering to?

Comment: I think i'm using the wrong interface: Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite.ISQLiteConnection
This is an interface of the MVVMCross SQLite Community Edition.

Comment: Any additional hints for me? Have you created an own MVVMCross plugin for SqlCipher that can be used in any other MVVMCross project? I'm very grateful for every help.